# compile error : "_for_stop_core" not found

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, icc, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to compile a c code which calls a fortran subroutine, but I always get error.

Here is the fortran code:

```
!fort_sub.f90
module myadd
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
contains

subroutine add1(a) bind(c)
implicit none
integer (c_int),intent (inout) :: a
a=a+1

if(a>10) then
   stop
endif
end subroutine add1
end module myadd
```

and here is the c code

```
//main.cpp
extern "C"{ void add1(int * a); }

int main(void){
  int a=2;
  add1(&a);
  return 0;
}
```

when I compile them with

```
ifort -c fort_subs.f90
icc main.cpp fort_subs.o
```

I get error

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_for_stop_core", referenced from:
>       _add1 in fort_subs.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> ```

and when I compile them with

```
icc -c main.cpp 
ifort -nofor-main fort_subs.f90 main.o
```

I get error

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
>       Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in main.o
>   "___intel_new_feature_proc_init", referenced from:
>       _main in main.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> ```

So why there are those errors and how to solve them?

I know in ibm compiler there is an option "-lxlf90" that tells the c compiler to link the fortran library, which resolves the "_for_stop_core" error. Is there a similar option in intel c compiler?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that C does not like Fortran's `STOP` command. If you want to stop the program, you might want to consider having a second value come in like

```
subroutine add1(a,kill) bind(c)
   integer (c_int), intent(inout) :: a, kill
   kill = 0
   a = a+1
   if(a > 10) kill=1
end subroutine
```

And in `main.cpp`,

```
//main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"{ void add1(int * a, int * kill); }

 int main(void){
  int a=20, kill;
  add1(&a, &kill);
  if(kill!=0) {
    printf("program halted due to a>10\n");
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my real code the stop is the not the last statement of the fortran subroutine. And it should be able to ask icc to bring in the fortran library to link. Do you know that flag? I know in ibm compiler, one can use `-lxlf90` flag to tell the c compiler to link the fortran library. Also I have a lot stop statement in the real code, change them by hand is tedious.

Comment: @xslittlegrass: I see, guess I hadn't considered that (for future reference: it might be worthwhile to mention little details like that in the question). I was able to get the program to compile and run by adding the compiler option `-lifcore`.

Comment: What is that -lifcore ? When I use that the icc doesn't recognize that : "ld: library not found for -lifcore"

Comment: What version of `icc` are you using? And on what platform? I have `icc 13.1.3` on Ubuntu linux and it does not give me any problems.

Comment: icc version 14.0.0 on OSX 10.8

Comment: Could the problem be C++ versus C?  What if you rename your C program main.c?

Comment: I did name the file `main.cpp`, but compiled it with `icc`; however, compiling that file with `icpc` gives me no errors again.

Comment: Not understanding your comment... does icpc with main.cpp fix your problem?  What about main.c with icc?

Comment: Sorry. I have the file named `main.cpp` but used `icc` to compile it with the flag `lifcore`. When I used `icpc` on the cpp file with the same flag,  I did not get any errors & it ran as it did when using the C compiler.